# How to change name of 'Browse' button with input type = 'file' and xtype='textfield'

Tags: extjs, extjs3

We are facing one strange issue where we are not able to change the button name from 'Browse' with file upload field.

We badly need this feature to support multiple languages. We are using xtype:textfield and input type as 'file'

Please help us to resolve this issue. We are using EXTJS 3.4

```
xtype:'textfield'
input type : 'file'
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a good extension that you can use for this.  It's in the examples for 3.4.

[File Upload Field Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/file-upload.html)

[FileUploadField.js](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/ux/fileuploadfield/FileUploadField.js)
[fileuploadield.css](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/ux/fileuploadfield/css/fileuploadfield.css)

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eRdhv/)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {


    new Ext.Viewport({


        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Textfield with inputType=file',
                        inputType: 'file'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                        width: 200,
                        emptyText: 'Select a file',
                        fieldLabel: 'FileUploadField UX',
                        name: 'blah-blah',
                        buttonText: 'Custom Text'
                    }
                ],

                title: 'Form'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type=text name=file style="width:60px"> 
<input type=file name=newfile style="display:none">
<input type=button onClick="newfile.click();file.value=newfile.value; " value="import from excel">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```